# John Hurt has passed away

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

John Hurt has died, at age 77. He played many great SFF roles – Kane in *Alien* (and *Spaceballs*), Winston Smith in *1984* and the Big Brother-like Sutler in *V for Vendetta*, Hadden in *Contact*, Professor Broom in *Hellboy*, Mr. Ollivander in the *Harry Potter* movies, and many more.

> “I hope I shall have the courage to say, 'Vroom! Here we go! Let's become different molecules!'”

Rest in peace, Sir John.

[image: Kane]

Comment: He didn't pass away - he regenerated into the next Doctor / Ollivander's Force ghost will be forever guiding us.

Comment: *Alien* is my favorite movie of all time. I recently watched two movies where he also died (he had a habit of dying in his movies, actually), *Contact* and *Tinker Tailor Soldier Spy* (not SFF), and I thought while I watched them that I was happy he was still around. I'll miss him.

Answer (score 22):

I especially enjoyed his portrayal of the elder Dante in the BBC Radio 4 production of Danté's [The Divine Comedy](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b03xtvdp), the melancholy War Doctor and his wonderfully over-the-top acting as High Chancellor Adam Sutler in V for Vendetta.

It saddens me that he's passed on.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 for mentioning _V for Vendetta_.  Great film!

Comment: Never noticed it before, even when watching the Who episode, but he really does look a bit like Christopher Eccleston, doesn't he? That gif you have there uses an angle where it's more evident than usual.

Answer (score 13):

John Hurt was one of the better parts of *Kingdom of the Crystal Skull*.

[image]

He also showed off his vocal range in *Watership Down*.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

My favorite sci-fi related John Hurt movies are:

- [*The Skeleton Key*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0397101/) as Ben Devereaux:

[image: Ben Devereaux]

- [*Only Lovers Left Alive*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1714915/) as Christopher Marlowe:

[image: Christopher Marlowe]

And of course, we cannot forget

- [*Alien*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078748/) as Kane:

[image: Kane]

**R.I.P. John Hurt.  You will be missed by all of your fans.**

Comment: Such a versatile actor.

Comment: Man, I forgot about *Only Lovers Left Alive*! *Furiously digs through film collection*

Comment: With regards to that last picture, some backstory about how that scene was filmed: http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/67777/13595 .

Answer (score 6):

I've always thought that 1984, starring John Hurt and Richard Burton, is one of the best film adaptations of any book, SFF or otherwise. The same can't be said of the animated Lord of the Rings (or any other film adaptation of that book). Still, John Hurt as the voice of Aragorn was a big plus point.

[image: aragorn]

Answer (score 4):

Let us not forget he was the voice of the Dragon, Kilgharrah, in BBC's Merlin

[image]

Comment: I've not seen it. Better than Bendlehurst Compostheap as Smaug?

Comment: @Valorum - the guy's name is Banderlick Crumblesnatch, silly.

Comment: Beneficient Cucumberhatch.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody else has mentioned it, so I will. John Hurt was fantastic as Professor Broom in Hellboy.

[image]

Wonderful cast all around, but Hurt was sorely missed for the sequel.

Comment: One could say he *cleaned up* in that role.

Comment: I did actually mention it in my question, but it deserves its own answer. Great role.

Answer (score 0):

I think he was the perfect choice for Kane in Alien -- his screen time was limited by his early death in the film, but he did such a good job of playing someone who, in my opinion, knew he was trouble even after he emerged from the medical  bay -- even though the audience knew for sure he was in for it, his character also sensed that such a crazy thing can't have happened for no reason -- the facehugger was not just hanging out. I forget why they could not see the embryo inside of him, but he did not know it. But all the same, I think he knew he was doomed.